# Python to Docker Issues

Tags: python, sql, docker, mysql-connector

I have created a Docker container running Azure SQL Edge on my Mac M1. I am able to run the container, connect to it with Azure Data Studio, and create/manipulate entries there. However, when I try to use mysql.connector.connect to access the server via a Python script, the connection just does nothing - no connection confirmation, no refusal, just hangs (or terminates at my timeout limit). Below is my code to create the Docker container, and the Python code I am running to try and access it:

sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=bigStrongPwd1!' -p 1433:1433  --name sqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='dbo.Customers',
                                     port=1433,
                                     user='sa',
                                     password='bigStrongPwd1!',
                                     use_pure=True,
                                     connection_timeout=5
)
```

When creating the Docker container, I have tried using different ports, using the -P flag, specifying the --network, etc. I have also tried checking the Docker container logs, and I cannot see any instance of the connection trying to be made. Also I have tried viewing the container in my browser and get "Safari can't open the page "localhost:1433" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again."

Comment: I've had similar issues trying to connect to a localhost db in the mac/docker/datastudio stack, but using pyodbc. Have not found a solution yet.